# Get first element from enumerable then iterate rest

Tags: c#, iteration, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable< Task< MyObject>> that effectively describes how to fetch a collection of items from cache.  The MyObject element has an error message and a success object.  I would like to do something like this:

```
List<MyObject> fetchAll(IEnumerable<Task<MyObject>> tasks)
{
    var (firstResponse, restOfEnumerable) = await tasks.DoSomethingToGetFirstResonseAndRestOfEnumerableAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if(!firstResponse.IsSuccess)
    {
        return null;
    }

    List<MyObject> ret = new List<MyObject>(firstResponse.Result);
    ret.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(restOfEnumerable).ConfigureAwait(false));
    return ret;
}
```

I know I could do this by calling ToList() on the enumerable and doing this

```
List<MyObject> fetchAll(List<Task<MyObject>> tasks)
    {
        var firstResponse = await tasks[0].ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!firstResponse.IsSuccess)
        {
            return null;
        }
    
        List<MyObject> ret = new List<MyObject>(firstResponse.Result);
        ret.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Skip(1)).ConfigureAwait(false));
        return ret;
    }
```

but I'm trying to not iterate the IEnumerable fully just to test the first item.

I suppose I could also drop down and get the enumerator myself like this

```
List<MyObject> fetchAll(IEnumerable<Task<MyObject>> tasks)
{
    var ret = new List<MyObject>();
    using (var enumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var firstResult = await enumerator.Current.ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!firstResponse.IsSuccess)
            {
                return null;
            }
            ret.Add(firstResponse.Result);
        }

        List<Task> restOfTasks = new List<Task>();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            restOfTasks.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }

        ret.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(restOfTasks).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
}
```

but I'm hoping there is something built in that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, I do not want to fully iterate the enumerable to test the first element and I do not want to cause a multiple enumeration of the enumerable (it may not always be possible to enumerate multiple times or it could be very expensive).

This is what I ended up doing - seems you have to drop down to the enumerator, there's no way to pass around a partially enumerated enumerable that I could figure out.

```
List<MyObject> fetchAll(IEnumerable<Task<MyObject>> tasks)
{
    var ret = new List<MyObject>();
    using (var enumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var firstResult = await enumerator.Current.ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!firstResponse.IsSuccess)
            {
                return ret;
            }
            ret.Add(firstResponse.Result);

            // if there are more, then get all the tasks and use Task.WhenAll to start them all at once and wait for them all to finish
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // also, we only create this task list if there are more
                var restOfTasks = new List<Task<MyObject>>();
                restOfTasks.Add(enumerator.Current);
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    restOfTasks.Add(enumerator.Current);
                }
                results.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(restOfTasks).ConfigureAwait(false));
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work with LINQ and use the method [Enumerable.First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0) to get the first element and [Enumerable.Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-6.0) to skip the first element in an iteration.

Comment: that would multiple enumerate the enumerable.  i'm trying to reuse the existing iterator.